# Getting an error when adding a 3rd-party jar file

Tags: corda

Good day,

I have modified the cordapp-tutorial demo application by modifying the gradle file \cordapp-tutorial\java-source\build.gradle. More specifically, I am adding a jar file to compile a 3rd party library. I'm making the following change to the build.gradle script

[image]
[image]

but it causes the following error for the M14 milestone release:
[image: Build fails when using M14]
    :java-source:configureCordappFatJar FAILED
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':java-source:configureCordappFatJar'.

> Cannot invoke method contains() on null object
>       * Try:
>       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>       BUILD FAILED

**I do not get this error when I am using milestone release M13**

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the Corda M14 gradle plugins. We are working to publish a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the 0.14.0 release of the Corda gradle plugins that caused this (a missing null check when checking with a dependency without a group).

The way to fix it would be to change the `corda_gradle_plugins_version` to `0.14.1`.

Comment: Clintonio, do you know of a better way of adding external jar file dependencies. Right now, I'm having to create a folder called libs with the jar file dependency next to it.

Comment: @Flethuseoin The template uses [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) as it's dependency management. You can use that, along with `compile` dependencies to compile against external JARs. The `cordformation` plugin will grab any `runtime` or `compile` dependency (except `cordaCompile` and `cordaRuntime`) and build them into your CorDapp.